# data passed to jquery .on(handler) comes out as undefined

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have three anchor tags that are added from an ajax $.get() response. 
I need to fire a second request when one of them is clicked.
The second request has parameters set by the the values of the html global data attributes in these anchors.

```
<div id="qbostatus">
    <a class='button radius small updateqbo' data-customer_id='1032' data-push='yes' data-create='no' style='margin-top:2em; margin-bottom:.4em;'>Accept and Push Changes</a>
    <a class='button radius small updateqbo' data-customer_id='1032' data-push='no' data-create='no' style='margin-bottom:.4em;'>Accept and Leave Alone</a>
    <a class='button radius small updateqbo' data-customer_id='' data-push='no' data-create='yes'>Reject and Create New</a>
</div>
<script>
    function updateQBO(event){
        console.log(event.data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            async: true,                
            url: "update_contact_updateQBO.php",
            success: function(result){
                $("#qbostatus").html(result);
            },
            data: {
                create: event.data.create,
                push: event.data.push,
                id: event.data.customer_id,
                fname: $("input[name='fname']").val(),
                lname: $("input[name='lname']").val(),
                email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
                street_address: $("input[name='street_address']").val(),
                city: $("input[name='city']").val(),
                state: $("input[name='state']").val(),
                zip: $("input[name='zip']").val(),
                phoneam: $("input[name='phoneam']").val(),
                phonepm: $("input[name='phonepm']").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            console.log(jqXHR, settings);
            console.log(create);
            console.log(push);
            console.log(id);

            }       
        });         
    }


    $("#qbostatus").on("click", ".updateqbo", {
        customer_id: $(this).attr('data-customer_id'),
        push: $(this).attr('data-push'),
        create: $(this).attr('data-create')},
        updateQBO);
```

Clicking any of these anchors creates the following console.log() output:

```
Object {customer_id: undefined, push: undefined, create: undefined}
```

Initially I figured something was wrong with the plain object containing the data which is passed to the event handler.  So I tested each of the selectors independently using an anonymous function as the handler to log the values to the console.  These selectors all appear to be working as follows:

```
    $("#qbostatus").on("click", ".updateqbo", 
        function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('data-customer_id'));
        console.log($(this).attr('data-push'));
        console.log($(this).attr('data-create'));
    });
```

Produces the following console log when the first anchor tag is clicked:

```
 1032
 yes
 no
```

So I'm still stumped on why the original code is passing "data-customer_id", "data-push", and "data-create" to updateQBO() as undefined.  Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ordqts47/ ?

Comment: sorry "{$Customer->Id}" should have been "1032" since thats what was actually echoed in the response to the first request.

Comment: Substituting correct values at `data-*` attribute, does jsfiddle return expected results ?

Comment: yes, but my real issue is that the handler in the first code block returns undefined values for those attributes.  have a look at 
[this:](http://jsfiddle.net/karikomi1/zLc531g6/)
although i have no idea why its showing the UncoughtReference error.  It doesnt do that on my machine

Comment: Inside of `beforeSend` ?

Comment: yes those are all undefined.  I believe the console output in my second code block is from "console.log(event.data);" which is the very first line of updateQBO.  so I know that all the attributes are getting sent with the handler below, just not with the right values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73543/discussion-between-user162241-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

html

Substituted `data-customerid='1023'` for `data-customer_id='1023'`

js

```
$(function() {
var updateQBO = function updateQBO(event) {
        var data = $(event.target).data();
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,                
            url: "/echo/json/",
            success: function(result){
                // $("#qbostatus").html(result);
            },
            data: {json:JSON.stringify({
                create: data.create,
                push: data.push,
                id: data.customerid,
                fname: $("input[name='fname']").val(),
                lname: $("input[name='lname']").val(),
                email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
                street_address: $("input[name='street_address']").val(),
                city: $("input[name='city']").val(),
                state: $("input[name='state']").val(),
                zip: $("input[name='zip']").val(),
                phoneam: $("input[name='phoneam']").val(),
                phonepm: $("input[name='phonepm']").val()
            })},
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
              var data = JSON.parse(
                           decodeURIComponent(settings.data.split(/=/)[1])
                         );
              console.log(jqXHR, settings);
              console.log(data.create, data.push, data.id);
            }       
        });         
    };

    var elem = $("#qbostatus");
    elem.on("click", ".updateqbo",updateQBO);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zLc531g6/2/